# asp.net mvc 4 - how to make header and lines record in same view . add delete edit record before submit

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new on asp.net mvc 4.

I have 2 tables, header and line table. The header table stores a question and the line table stores the answer.
In this survey application, the User will enter the questions and after that will enter the asnwers. The User can add multiple answers and before submitting he can delete some of them.

What is the best way to do this, jquery,javascripts...

I couldn't find the best way.

My view will be as below...

```
<div id="mysurvey">
    <div id="myquestion">
       -- in this section , there will be an image, and a text area
    </div>
    <div id="answers">
       <div id="answer1">
       -- in this section , there will be an image, and a text area
       </div>
       <div id="answer2">
       -- in this section , there will be an image, and a text area
       </div>
       <div id="answer3">
       -- in this section , there will be an image, and a text area
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Knock Out MVC library](http://knockoutmvc.com/). [This example](http://knockoutmvc.com/ContactsEditor) is pretty much what you are wanting to do. And there are a lot of other well documented examples and tutorials online.